# Pars Application doesn't accept string

Tags: android

I'm making a android app . 
I wanna make a RSS reader application . 
I get help of an Udemy's course , I almost copy all the codes , what codes he has said on course , but I've got problem! contrariwise video course ! 
I have problem in this codes :

```
private String mFileContents;
private Button btnParse;
private ListView xmlList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnParse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnParse);
    btnParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseApplications parseApplications = new ParseApplications(mFileContents);
            parseApplications.process();
            ArrayAdapter<Application> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Application>(
                    MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, parseApplications.getApplications());
            xmlList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });
    xmlList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xmlList);
    DownloadData downloadData = new DownloadData();
    downloadData.execute("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml");
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

my APP will connect to 10 top apps of apple market and show them ( show apps' name and artist and release date between two line ) 
It should be like this :
[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGvkl.png)

instead that my app get error and stop ! and as far as I know that get error for 'mFileContents' , it is string but as Android Studio comment : I must make a public string in ParseApplications class ! but when I do that , app doesn't work still ! how can I resolve that ?